# Office UI Fabric React - DetailsList Columns's width auto adjust based on content size

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

We are populating the DetailsList with SharePoint list view data. The columns are built dynamically. We are currently adjusting the column width by specifying minwidth and maxwidth. But as the columns are dynamic, sometimes this cause free space to right (depending on number of columns) and does not fit the entire web part content. Is there any way the column's width can be adjusted based on size of content?

Answer (score 0):

The DetailList does not support this. See the discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/9287